# How to match the key in array map to display the same element from my list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I am displaying from an array with map my images. And when I click on an image I open a new page. On the new Page I want to display the same image that I clicked on. (only this one that was clicked). My issue now is that it currently displays always the last image from my array list. No matter what image I click on. And I dont know how to match the image that I clicked with the key id so it shows the correct image I want?

```
export default function MyPhotos() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const openNewPage = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

return (
  <div>
    {contents.map((content) => {
      return (
        <div key={content.id}>
          <img // here all my images are displayed, works as expexted
            onClick={openNewPage}  //when I click on the image, I get redirected to another page and I want there to display the same image that I just clicked on
            src={content.image}
          />
          <PageComponent isOpen={isOpen} onClose={openNewPage}>
              <img
                onClick={openNewPage}
                src={content.image} //here once the page opens only the last image from my list is displayed always. But I want it to mathc with the image that I clicked..
              />
          </PageComponent>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
    );
  }
```

Thats how my array of objects looks like, I did not paste the whole list.

```
[{
    id: 0,
    item_key: Img0,
    text: "ABC"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    image: Img1,
    text: "ABCD"
  }
]
```

Comment: sounds like you have n popups opening at the same time, and what you saw is just the top one, i.e. the last one

Comment: I am not sure but I think it opens only one popup but always with the last image element.

Comment: your `PageComponent` is inside the map loop, all sharing 1 same `isOpen` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you sending an `<img />` as a child of that component? Put that `<img />` tag into `<PageComponent`, then send your image as a prop. Like below,

```
<PageComponent isOpen={isOpen} onClose={openNewPage} imgSrc = {content.image} />
```

Then, in `PageComponent.jsx` , show your `<img` like below

```
export default function PageComponent(props) {
....
return
<img src={props.imgSrc}
```

If pages are dynamically change, you can listen that in a `useEffect` as well in `PageComponent.jsx`

```
const [imgSrc, setimgSrc] = useState("")
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setimgSrc(props.imgSrc)
  }, [props.imgSrc])
```

But then, you have to put `imgSrc` instead of `props.imgSrc` into `<img` tag

```
export default function PageComponent({props}) {
....
return
<img src={imgSrc}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try that. But is there no way to "listen" to the key={content.id} in order to match the displayed image?

Comment: Well, since you are mapping through your array, it'll show the last element because it'll put the last content.img to your component. To match it, you need something like `src={content.id === something && content.image}`. But you have to store that `something` somewhere, then check if they match. This is more hard work then what I did in my answer.